# how to send a comma separated list into in clause?

Tags: sql, database, csv

I am trying to pass a list of comma separated email ids a@b.com,s@b.com into sql in clause is my query right please give some suggestions

```
 SELECT * FROM service.cs_list_of_email_ids where Email in (
        SELECT regexp_substr(:a@b.com,s@b.com,'[^,]+', 1, level) items
        FROM dual
        CONNECT BY regexp_substr(:a@b.com,s@b.com, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
    );
```

Comment: Is it? Why are you asking us? Does it work or not? :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885076/how-to-split-string-and-insert-values-into-table-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mentioned if you are using `Sql Server` then you can create this function for splitting the comma separated string

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
-- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
  id int identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
GO
```

Then call it as below

```
SELECT * FROM service.cs_list_of_email_ids where Email in 
       (SELECT val FROM dbo.split(@str,','))
```