# How to realize reverse "NOT IN"?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've got a table A with some data:

```
name
------
a
b
d
```

And I've got a list of names (`'a', 'b', 'c', 'e'`) from which I would like to get those values that are *not in* the table. How can I do this? Which options do I have? This is not working (of course):

```
SELECT value FROM ('a', 'b', 'c', 'e') WHERE value NOT IN (SELECT name FROM A)
```

In this example the expected result would be:

```
value
------
c
e
```

Answer (score 4):

You can build a temp table with `union` and then join against it

```
select tmp.name
from
(
  select 'a' as name
  union all 
  select 'b'
  union all 
  select 'c'
  union all 
  select 'e'
) tmp
left join your_table t on t.name = tmp.name
where t.name is null
```

When you have more than just a few values I recommend putting those values into a real table and then join against it.

Comment: I see. Yes, I have more values. So another table is the only option then?

Comment: Another table is the only real option here.

Answer (score 0):

Go to given below link you will get SPLIT function , just create this function it will be for future developement also.
[How to split string and insert values into table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885076/how-to-split-string-and-insert-values-into-table-in-sql-server)

After that Excecute the below query.

```
SELECT * 
into #temp
FROM [dbo].Split('a,b,c,e', ',')

select * from #temp where item not in (select * from A)

drop table #temp
```