# New column from existing column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with values

```
Name
-----------
John Smith
Lee Tom
Farm Tom Ville
Jack Midu mark LLC
```

is there any query in sql server that can create dynamic columns for each word.

[image: Sample]

I have attached an image with required output.
I have almost 1.5 million records of data.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885076/how-to-split-string-and-insert-values-into-table-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split string and insert values into table in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885076/how-to-split-string-and-insert-values-into-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: i am using ms sql server

Answer (score 1):

Please check following SQL query

```
;with cte as (
    select
        [name],
        id,
        val
    from names
    cross apply dbo.split([name],' ') 
), mydata as (
select
    [name],
    case when id = 1 then val end as name1,
    case when id = 2 then val end as name2,
    case when id = 3 then val end as name3,
    case when id = 4 then val end as name4,
    case when id = 5 then val end as name5
from cte
)
select
    [name],
    max(name1) name1,
    max(name2) name2,
    max(name3) name3,
    max(name4) name4,
    max(name5) name5
from mydata
group by [name]
```

I used a user-defined [SQL split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx), you can find the source codes in referred document
Even though you could use [SQL STRING_SPLIT function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/split-string-function-in-sqlserver-2016.aspx) introduced with SQL Server 2016, since it does not return the order like the referred split function it will not be useful in the above pivot-like query

To visualize the output please check following result set

[image]

Comment: I think the omission of the position by MS is a HUGE miss. I would suggest checking out this splitter. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ It returns the position but is an inline table valued function instead of the multi statement one at the link you shared. It will be quite a bit faster.

Comment: Yes I know, the classic solution is still the fastest one against all those fancy solutions (CTEs, XML, CLR, etc)