# Is there any way to loop a string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, select, stored-procedures

I am trying to loop a varchar in SQL Server, one of the columns has the format

```
"F1 100 F2 400 F3 600"
```

What I need is to take the numbers and divide by 10: "F1 10 F2 40 F3 60", for the moment I have a stored procedure which calls this function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [name_offunction]
    (@Chain varchar(120)) 
RETURNS varchar(120
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(120), @Pos int, @Concat varchar(120)

    WHILE LEN(@Chain) > 0
    BEGIN
         SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(' ', @Chain)
         SET @Result = CASE
                           WHEN SUBSTRING(@Chain, 1, @Pos-1) LIKE '%[^A-Z]%' 
                                 THEN SUBSTRING(@Chain, 1, @Pos-1)
                           WHEN SUBSTRING(@Chain, 1, @Pos-1) NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%' 
                                 THEN CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(@Chain, 1, @Pos-1) / 10 AS INT)AS CHAR)
                       END
         SET @Chain = REPLACE(@Chain, SUBSTRING(@Chain, 1, @Pos), '')
         SET @Concat += @Result + ' '
   END
   RETURN @Concat
```

Comment: Why do you want to loop in SQL Server at all? SQL Server is a set based language; the *last* thing you should be doing is looping.

Comment: probably you can split your string, put splitted values into table... and then try to divide each rowvalue by 10... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885076/how-to-split-string-and-insert-values-into-table-in-sql-server/46695204 as example how to split

Comment: @Larnu, that's why I'm asking, to find the best solution, I know I shouldn't do a loop........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We seem to have 2 problems here. Firstly the fact that you want to loop in SQL, however, SQL is a set based language. This means that it performs great at set-based operations but poorly at iterative ones, such as a loop.

Next is that you have what appears to be delimited data, and that you want to affect that delimited data in some way, and the reconstruct the data into a delimited string. Storing delimited data in a database is always a design flaw, and you should really be fixing said design.

I would therefore propose you move to an inline table-value function over a scalar function.

Firstly, as it appears that the ordinal position of the values is important we *can't* use SQL Server's built in `STRING_SPLIT`, as it is documented to not guarantee the order of the values will be the same. I am therefore going to use [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function) which gives the ordinal position.

Then we can use `TRY_CONVERT` to check to see if the value is an `int` (I assume this is the correct data type), and if it is divide by `10`. Finally we can reconstruct the data using `STRING_AGG`.

Outside of a function this would look like this:

```sql
DECLARE @Chain varchar(120) = 'F1 100 F2 400 F3 600';

SELECT STRING_AGG(COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(10),TRY_CONVERT(int,DS.item)/10),DS.item),' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DS.Item)
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@Chain,' ') DS;
```

As a function, you could therefore do this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.YourFunction (@Chain varchar(120))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
    SELECT STRING_AGG(COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(10),TRY_CONVERT(int,DS.item)/10),DS.item),' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DS.Item) AS NewChain
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@Chain,' ') DS;
GO
```

And call is as such:

```sql
SELECT YF.NewChain
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.YourFunction (YT.Chain) YF;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aa881adcefe067b3cc057e6d3f93dfbf)

Note that `STRING_AGG` was introduced in SQL Server 2017; if you're using an older version (you don't note this is the question) you'll need to use the "old" `FOR XML PATH` solution, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49361088/string-agg-for-sql-server-pre-2017).