# SQL query adjusts the string column

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

a little just a continuation of my last topic.
I have table:

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2;1|3;5|4;8|9;8|10;12 |
| 2 | 0;2|1;3|5;6 |
| 3 | 3;5|1;5|4;7|6;9 |

Column values is varchar and i need modify, that I get each number separately

I don't care if in new columns or as separate values in the same column.

| id | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 12 |

or

| id | values | x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 | x3 | y3 | x4 | y4 | x5 | y5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2;1|3;5|4;8|9;8|10;12 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 8 | 9 | 8 | 10 | 12 |

Both solutions would be great for me.
i tried to achieve this at sql level and potentially using ssis:

```
SELECT values,
        SUBSTRING(values, 1, CHARINDEX(';', values)-1) AS x1,
        SUBSTRING(values,1,CHARINDEX(';', values)+1) AS y1
       /*CONVERT(float,STUFF(values,1,CHARINDEX(';',values),'')) AS y1
       CONVERT(float,LEFT(UserGuid,CHARINDEX(';',UserGuid)-1)) AS x1
      ,CONVERT(float,LEFT(UserGuid,CHARINDEX(';',UserGuid)-1)) AS x2,
       ,SUBSTRING(UserGuid, CHARINDEX(';', UserGuid) + 1, 1000) AS y2 */
FROM table
```

But I was told that this would be difficult to achieve at the sql level.

This adjustment may be necessary using some side scripting, any idea and suggestion will be great for me.
Thank you

Comment: I suggest doing this cleanup work outside of SQL Server (e.g. using Java, PHP, Notepad++, etc.), then reimporting your data.  This problem is not well handled by a database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and for example some python script would also go do you think?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869048/is-there-any-way-to-loop-a-string-in-sql-server

Comment: @DaleK Sorry, I have already added my question. I'm more interested in an idea than a solution than a solution as such. So you don't get me wrong.

Comment: @DaleK Of course. But when the problem, for example, cannot be solved in the way I intended. I have to change the solution, but the problem remains. In this case, I'm happy for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` twice, this gets you all the values in rows:

```sql
SELECT t.id, s2.[value]
FROM Yourtable t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.values, '|') s1
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s1.[value], ';') s2
```